# Exact sub-string match inside a string in Python

Tags: python, string

1. I have a string as given below

   ```
   dit ='{p_d: {a:3, what:3.6864e-05, s:lion, sst:{c:-20, b:6, p:panther}}}'
   ```
2. And I have a list of elements which I wanted to search in the above string and replace them with double quotes.

   ```
   ['', 'p_d', '', '', 'a', '3', '', 'what', '3.6864e-05', '', 's', 'lion', '', 'sst', '', 'c', '-20', '', 'b', '6', '', 'p', 'panther', '', '', '']
   ```
3. If I do search and replace using simple .replace it doesn't work as expected and can understand

   ```
   import yaml
   import ast
   import json
   import re

   rep = {":": " ", "'":" ", "{":" ", "}":" ", ",": " "}
   quot = "\""
   dit = '{p_d: {a:3, what:3.6864e-05, s:lion, sst:{c:-20, b:6, p:panther}}}'

   def replace_all(text, dic):
     for i, j in dic.items():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
        print("replace_all: text {}".format(text))
     return text

   element_list_temp = replace_all(dit, rep)
   element_list = element_list_temp.split(" ")

   for z in element_list:
       if z != "" and z in dit:
           dit = dit.replace(z, quot+z+quot)
   print(dit)



   Output:
   {""p"_d": {"a":"3", wh"a"t:"3"."6"8"6"4e-05, "s":"lion", "s""s"t:{"c":"-20", "b":"6", "p":"p""a"nther}}}

   Desired Output:
   '{"p_d": {"a":"3", "what":"3.6864e-05", "s":"lion", "sst":{"c":"-20", "b":"6", "p":"panther"}}}'
   ```
4. How to exactly match the string in the list one by one and replace them with double quotes.

Updates:

1. Different input

   ```
   import yaml
   import ast
   import json
   import re

   rep = {":": " ", "'":" ", "{":" ", "}":" ", ",": " "}
   quot = "\""

   # dit = '{p_d: {a:3, what:3.6864e-05, s:lion, sst:{c:-20, b:6, p:panther}}}'
   dit = "'{p_d: '{a:3, what:3.6864e-05, s:lion, vec_mode:'{2.5, -2.9, 3.4, 5.6, -8.9, -5.67, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5.4, 2, 2, 6.545, 2, 2}, sst:'{c:-20, b:6, p:panther}}}"

   seps = ":'{}, "

   val_strings = re.findall(f"[^{seps}]+", dit)
   print("val_strings: {}".format(val_strings))

   sep_strings = re.findall(f"[{seps}]+", dit)
   print("sep_strings: {}".format(sep_strings))

   seq = [f'{b}"{v}"' for b, v in zip(sep_strings, val_strings)] + sep_strings[-1:]
   print("sep: {}".format(seq))

   dit = "".join(seq)
   print(dit)

   Dict = json.loads(dit) 
   print(Dict)

   result = yaml.dump(Dict)
   print(result)
   print(result.replace("'",""))
   ```
2. Output from above code

Think its failing because of the key:value pair of the dictionary. Checking at my end as well if there is a way to print them as arrays.

```
   val_strings: ['p_d', 'a', '3', 'what', '3.6864e-05', 's', 'lion', 'vec_mode', '2.5', '-2.9', '3.4', '5.6', '-8.9', '-5.67', '2', '2', '2', '2', '5.4', '2', '2', '6.545', '2', '2', 'sst', 'c', '-20', 'b', '6', 'p', 'panther']
   sep_strings: ["'{", ": '{", ':', ', ', ':', ', ', ':', ', ', ":'{", ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', ', '}, ', ":'{", ':', ', ', ':', ', ', ':', '}}}']
   sep: ['\'{"p_d"', ': \'{"a"', ':"3"', ', "what"', ':"3.6864e-05"', ', "s"', ':"lion"', ', "vec_mode"', ':\'{"2.5"', ', "-2.9"', ', "3.4"', ', "5.6"', ', "-8.9"', ', "-5.67"', ', "2"', ', "2"', ', "2"', ', "2"', ', "5.4"', ', "2"', ', "2"', ', "6.545"', ', "2"', ', "2"', '}, "sst"', ':\'{"c"', ':"-20"', ', "b"', ':"6"', ', "p"', ':"panther"', '}}}']
   '{"p_d": '{"a":"3", "what":"3.6864e-05", "s":"lion", "vec_mode":'{"2.5", "-2.9", "3.4", "5.6", "-8.9", "-5.67", "2", "2", "2", "2", "5.4", "2", "2", "6.545", "2", "2"}, "sst":'{"c":"-20", "b":"6", "p":"panther"}}}
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "./ditoyaml_new.py", line 36, in <module>
       Dict = json.loads(dit) 
     File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
       return _default_decoder.decode(s)
     File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
     File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
       raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
   json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Expected Output with the json.load and dump as dictionary and if the key: value dictionary pair isnt available and put something like list or array. Checking at my end as well. 
p_d:
  a: 3
  s: lion
  sst:
    b: 6
    c: -20
    p: panther
  vec_mode:
    [-8.9,
    -5.67,
    -2.9,
    2,
    2.5,
    3.4,
    5.4,
    5.6,
    6.545]
  what: 3.6864e-05
```

Comment: The values in 1. are not a string and those in 2. are not formatted as a list.  Can you edit it so that they have the correct formatting for strings and lists?  I.e. `dit = '...'` and `[a, b, c, ...]`

Comment: Also, might help if you show the desired output as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way using regular expressions

```
import re

dit = '{p_d: {a:3, what:3.6864e-05, s:lion, sst:{c:-20, b:6, p:panther}}}'
seps = ":'{}, "

val_strings = re.findall(fr"[^{seps}]+", dit)
sep_strings = re.findall(fr"[{seps}]+", dit)
seq = [f'{b}"{v}"' for b, v in zip(sep_strings, val_strings)] + sep_strings[-1:]
dit = "".join(seq)
print(dit)
```

Output:

```
{"p_d": {"a":"3", "what":"3.6864e-05", "s":"lion", "sst":{"c":"-20", "b":"6", "p":"panther"}}}
```

JSON test:

```
import json

print(json.loads(dit))
```

Output:

```
{'p_d': {'a': '3', 'what': '3.6864e-05', 's': 'lion', 'sst': {'c': '-20', 'b': '6', 'p': 'panther'}}}
```

Comment: thanks @bill for your inputs. But faced an error when my input is dit = "'{p_d: '{a:3, what:3.6864e-05, s:lion, vec_mode:'{2.5, -2.9, 3.4, 5.6, -8.9, -5.67, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5.4, 2, 2, 6.545, 2, 2}, sst:'{c:-20, b:6, p:panther}}}"

Updated the above post.

Comment: That different input seems invalid.  I can't see how it should be processed if it starts with a `'` character. What do you expect? Incidentally, where is this input text coming from? What is the protocol it follows?